# how to solve this error? "lazy-load in not a function"

Tags: lazy-loading, jquery-isotope, es6-modules

I use isotope plugin and lazy-sizes to build a photo gallery. but lazy-loading doesn't work and i get this error: "lazyload is not a function".

is there any idea for this issue and how to implement both plugins together?

```
    npm install lazysizes --save
    npm install isotope-layout --save
```

this is my code:

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';
    import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';
    import imagesLoaded from 'imagesloaded';
    import lazyload from 'lazysizes';
    jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
    jQueryBridget( 'imagesLoaded', imagesLoaded, $ );

    class isotopeGallrey {
      constructor() {
        this.Grid = $(".grid");
        this.itemImage = $(".grid-item img");
        this.createIsotope();
      }

      createIsotope() {
        var that = this;
        this.Grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
          that.Grid.isotope({
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            containerClass: 'isotope',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            percentPosition: true
          });
          that.itemImage.lazyload({
            effect: 'fadeIn'
          });
          that.itemImage.trigger('scroll');
         });
      }
    }

    export default isotopeGallrey;
```

Comment: The line `import lazyload from 'lazysizes';` is based on which documentation? can you provide a link?

Comment: I think the problem is exactly here, i don't know how to import lazy-load correctly to my project.